# Having problems starting EXWM

Tags: debian, exwm

I am running Debian 9.3. I created an .xinitrc file and a symlink, .xsession. File permission was changed to 774.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# This is a sample file for the ~/.xinitrc file.
#
# Set fallback cursor
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

# If Emacs is started in server mode, `emacsclient` is a convenient way         to edit
# files in place (used by e.g. `git commit`)
export VISUAL=emacsclient
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"

# Disable access control
xhost +SI:localuser:$USER

## Over-rides
#
xset b off &
#numlockx off                    # Turn off numlock

# Set keyboard repeat rate
xset r rate 180 40

nm-applet
exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session emacs
```

My init.el has the following:

```
(require 'exwm)
(require 'exwm-config)

(setq exwm-workspace-number 4)

(require 'exwm-randr)
(setq exwm-randr-workspace-output-plist '(0 "VGA1"))
(add-hook 'exwm-randr-screen-change-hook
      (lambda ()
        (start-process-shell-command
         "xrandr" nil "xrandr --output VGA1 --left-of LVDS1 --auto")))
(exwm-randr-enable)

[...]

;; Global keybindings can be defined with `exwm-input-global-keys'.
;; Here are a few examples:
(setq exwm-input-global-keys
  `(
    ;; Bind "s-r" to exit char-mode and fullscreen mode.
    ([?\s-r] . exwm-reset)
    ;; Bind "s-w" to switch workspace interactively.
    ([?\s-w] . exwm-workspace-switch)
    ;; Bind "s-0" to "s-9" to switch to a workspace by its index.
    ,@(mapcar (lambda (i)
                `(,(kbd (format "s-%d" i)) .
                  (lambda ()
                    (interactive)
                    (exwm-workspace-switch-create ,i))))
              (number-sequence 0 9))
    ;; Bind "s-&" to launch applications ('M-&' also works if the output
    ;; buffer does not bother you).
    ([?\s-&] . (lambda (command)
                 (interactive (list (read-shell-command "$ ")))
                 (start-process-shell-command command nil command)))
    ;; Bind "s-<f2>" to "slock", a simpl0e X display locker.
    ([s-f2] . (lambda ()
                (interactive)
                (start-process "" nil "/usr/bin/slock")))))

;; To add a key binding only available in line-mode, simply define it in
;; `exwm-mode-map'.  The following example shortens 'C-c q' to 'C-q'.
(define-key exwm-mode-map [?\C-q] #'exwm-input-send-next-key)

(setq exwm-input-simulation-keys
  '(
    ;; movement
    ([?\C-b] . [left])
    ))

;; Do not forget to enable EXWM. It will start by itself when things are
;; ready.  You can put it _anywhere_ in your configuration.
(exwm-enable)
```

When I ran xinit -- vt01 in a virtual console, I received the following error:

(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.
[...]
XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0" after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

I'm not sure how to resolve this, and would appreciate suggestions. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:** jue's answer did the trick. I am now encountering a different problem--I've attempted a multi-monitor setup, but do not know how to open emacs in more than one monitor. I cannot seem to bind anything using exwm-input-global-keys with the Super key; funny enough, I am able to setq exwm-input-simulation keys properly. Does anyone know how to have emacs frames open in both monitors in the same workspace?

Comment: You should put your edit in a new question otherwise no one will read it. I can't help you there, because I'm using the fantastic and unbeatable  `fvwm2` window manager. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I d not know your system setup or system knowledge, but this error message means on your system is an X-server running already and X11 cannot use that display (number `0`) again.
So either you stop that X-server before launching xinit. Or you use another display for this new server.
If you just booted you Linux box with that `.xinitrc` file, then chances are good, your exwm is already running.

You could try following command: `xinit xterm -- :1 vt08` to start a new X-server with just an xterm on another display (number `1`).
If that works, quit this new x-server and try:
`xinit emacs -- :1 vt08` or `xinit -- :1 vt08`.

Comment: I'm now encountering two unrelated problems, which I amended the OP to describe. I don't know how to open more than one emacs frame in a given workspace (ideally i would have one in each monitor), and I'm having trouble binding exwm-input-global-keys. Would you happen to have any suggestions?